# Can I make a donut chart without external file for data?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I've been trying to understand why one particular visualization hasn't been appearing the way I want. Examples I've seen, like [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235) one and [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193) one, all use some other file (whether it's json, csv or tsv). Is it possible to make the donut without, and just put the data as I did in the "tags" variable? There's not a lot of data to use, and the csv/tsv file wouldn't really have a place to be stored.

My code is below. It's ideally supposed to be just a donut with the tag names appended to each sector, e.g. a blue sector that says "translation" on it. Thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--<title>D3 Visualization></title>-->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<!--Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--CSS Styling-->
<style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
    }
    .arcstyle {
        stroke: white;
        font: 0.5em;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var w = 1000;
        var h = 1000;

        var svgBody = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

        //Doing the connection of tags to annulus
        var tags = [{
            tag: "translation",
            authors: "smith",
            tcolor: "blue"
        }, {
            tag: "code",
            authors: "finch",
            tcolor: "green"
        }, {
            tag: "samples",
            authors: "chang",
            tcolor: "red"
        }, {
            tag: "nodes",
            authors: "thomas",
            tcolor: "yellow"
        }];


        //Shape of the outer ring (tags)
        var arcGroup = svgBody.append("g") //.data(tags)
            .attr("transform", "translate(500,500)");

        var arcShape = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(425)
            .outerRadius(575)
            .startAngle(0)
            .endAngle(2 * Math.PI);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function(d) {
                return 2 * Math.PI / tags.length
            });

        var gA = arcGroup.selectAll(".arcstyle")
            .data(pie(tags))
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");

        gA.append("path")
            .attr("d", arcShape)
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                return d.tcolor
            });

        gA.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + arcShape.centroid(d) + ")"
            })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style('fill', 'white')
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.tag
            });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the problems:

1. You're setting the start angle and the end angle in your arc generator:

   ```
   var arcShape = d3.svg.arc()
       .innerRadius(425)
       .outerRadius(575)
       .startAngle(0)
       .endAngle(2*Math.PI);
   ```

   Drop that:

   ```
   var arcShape = d3.svg.arc()
       .innerRadius(425)
       .outerRadius(575);
   ```
2. To access the data of your slices, you have to use `d.data`:

   ```
   .style("fill", function(d) {
       return d.data.tcolor
   });
   ```
3. The `value` really doesn't matter, because all the slices have the same length. You can return any number:

   ```
   .value(function(d) {
       return 1
   });
   ```

Also, use `.style("text-anchor", "middle")` for the texts.

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var w = 500;
 var h = 500;

 var svgBody = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", w)
   .attr("height", h);

 //Doing the connection of tags to annulus
 var tags = [{
   tag: "translation",
   authors: "smith",
   tcolor: "blue"
 }, {
   tag: "code",
   authors: "finch",
   tcolor: "green"
 }, {
   tag: "samples",
   authors: "chang",
   tcolor: "red"
 }, {
   tag: "nodes",
   authors: "thomas",
   tcolor: "yellow"
 }];


 //Shape of the outer ring (tags)
 var arcGroup = svgBody.append("g") //.data(tags)
   .attr("transform", "translate(250,250)");

 var arcShape = d3.svg.arc()
   .innerRadius(200)
   .outerRadius(250);

 var pie = d3.layout.pie()
   .sort(null)
   .value(function(d) {
     return 1
   });

 var gA = arcGroup.selectAll(".arcstyle")
   .data(pie(tags))
   .enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "arc");

 gA.append("path")
   .attr("d", arcShape)
   .style("fill", function(d) {
     return d.data.tcolor
   });

 gA.append("text")
   .attr("transform", function(d) {
     return "translate(" + arcShape.centroid(d) + ")"
   })
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
   .style('fill', 'white')
   .text(function(d) {
     return d.data.tag
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```